# Meet me in/at college

Tags: prepositions

Meet me **in** college tomorrow.

Meet me **at** college tomorrow.

Which of these two sentences do we say?

Comment: [Closely related question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/32515/preposition-confusion-do-you-learn-somthing-at-school-or-in-school).

Answer (score 3):

I probably wouldn't say either one of those; I'd say:

> Meet me **on campus** tomorrow.

although I might get away with:

> Meet me at **the** college tomorrow.

In this context, I wouldn't use *in* as a word for a meeting point, not unless we were meeting inside a particular room or building:

> Meet me **in the lobby** of the engineering building tomorrow.

---

The phrase *in college* usually doesn't reference a location, but to the full college experience:

> I studied biology in college.
>   I partied a lot while I was in college.
>   I had to work nights while I was in college.
>   Tony is in the army, but his two sisters are in college.

The phrase *at college* can be used to reference a campus, particular one that isn't nearby:

> We don't see Rachel very often now that she's at college.
>   I met my wife Tracy at college.

Comment: I agree with you

Comment: The last example is good for showing when the definite article is needed. Saying someone is "at college" is appropriate when you don't care what specific college it is. For meeting someone, however, you'd say they were "at the college", since it is important which one you're talking about.